# Dereferencing Conditionally in Perl

Tags: perl, reference

I have a scalar that may or may not be a reference to an array. If it is a reference to an array, I would like to dereference it and iterate over it. If not, I would like to treat it as a one-element array and iterate over that.

```
my $result = my_complicated_expression;
for my $value (ref($result) eq 'ARRAY' ? @$result : ($result)) {
    # Do work with $value
}
```

Currently, I have the above code, which works fine but feels clunky and not very Perlish. Is there a more concise way to express the idea of dereferencing a value with fallback behavior if the value is not what I expect?

Comment: And what's not Perlish to this code? If you have your own standard module included in every script, you can hide this dereferencing in a function exported from that module. Additionally, you can sequence hashes, too.

Comment: The main thing that bothers me is the fact that the name appears three times in the line. I'd like to avoid that temporary `$result` variable altogether, but that may be asking too much.

Comment: Don't you have control over `my_complicated_expression`? Why aren't you *always* returning an array ref?

Comment: I don't. It makes a call to someone else's old library code that's (if you ask me) written pretty sloppily. That's why I have this problem.

Comment: It's not very Perlish, but that's because your design is not very Perlish. Generally, you want a design that doesn't make you check what type of data a scalar contains, since such checks aren't generally reliable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being perl, there's going to be several answers to this with the 'right' one being a matter of taste - IMHO, an acceptable shortening involves relying on the fact that [the ref function returns the empty string](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html) if the expression given it is scalar.  This means you don't need the `eq 'ARRAY'` if you know there are only two possibilities (ie, a scalar value and an array ref).

Secondly, you can iterate over a single scalar value (producing 1 iteration, obviously), so you don't have to put the `$result` in parentheses in the "scalar" case.

Putting these two small simplifications togeather gives;

```
use v5.12;

my $result1 = "Hello World";
my $result2 = [ "Hello" , "World" ];

for my $result ($result1, $result2) {
    for my $value ( ref $result ? @$result : $result) {
        say $value ;
    }
}
```

which produces;

```
Hello World
Hello
World
```

There's likely to be 'fancier' things you can do, but this seems a reasonable compromise between being terse and readable.  Of course, YMMV.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have that luxury. It's very possible that the value in question is in fact a hash reference, not necessarily just a scalar, in which case I'd like it to do the second thing and iterate once as well.

Comment: If its a hashref, do you want the keys, the values, or both?  Also, how do you "do the second thing" with a hashref?  The second thing was to print one scalar value, but if you have a hash, there's going to be more than one value.

Comment: If it's a hashref, I want to iterate once over the single value which is the whole hashref. I don't want the loop to do anything special unless it's an array ref specifically.

Comment: Then you are going to have to check for ARRAY ref specifically.  I'm going to leave my answer as is for others who don't have the "other possibilities" problem.  The other possibility is to modify whatever is producing the result to always return an array ref.

Comment: Well, it was worth a shot, but I suppose you answered my question, even though I'm not fond of the conclusion. I'll just have to do it the long way.

Answer (score 4):

Just force it before the loop.

### Limited, known ref type

```
my $result = *some function call* // [];
$result    = [$result] if ref $result ne 'ARRAY';

for my $val ( @$result ){
   print $val;
}
```

## Ref type unknown

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.012;

use strict;
no warnings;

sub array_ref;

my $result = [qw/foo bar foobar/];
 # $result = 'foo';         # scalar test case 
 # $result = {foo=>q{bar}}; # hash   test case
$result = array_ref $result;

for my $val ( @$result ){
  say $val;
}

sub array_ref {
  my $ref = shift;
  given(ref $ref){
    $ref = [%$ref] when('HASH');
    $ref = [$ref]  when(['SCALAR','']);
    when('ARRAY'){}
    default {
      die 'Did not prepare for other ref types';
    }
  }
  return $ref;
}
```

This is for demo purposes (you shouldn't use given/when in production code), but shows you could easily test for the ref type and cast a new response.  However, if you really don't know what type of variable your function is returning, how are you sure it's even a reference.  What if it was an array or hash?

Answer (score 1):

I see that I'm late to this, but I can't help it. With `eval` and `$@`, and the comma operator

```
my $ra = [ qw(a b c) ];
my $x = 23;

my $var = $ra;
# my $var = $x;    # swap comment to test the other

foreach my $el ( eval { @{$var} }, $@ && $var ) 
{
    next if $el =~ /^$/;  # when @$var is good comma adds empty line
    print $el, "\n";
}
```

Prints `a b c` (one per line), if we swap to `my $var = $x` it prints `23`.

When `$var` has the reference, the `$@` is empty but the comma is still executed and this adds an empty line, thus the `next` in the loop. Alternatively to skipping empty lines one can filter them out

```
foreach my $el ( grep { !/^$/ } eval { @{$var} }, $@ && $var )
```

---

This does, in addition, clean out empty lines.  However, most of the time that is desirable.

Comment: I have to add: with all that punctuation this is "Perlish" as wanted, no?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo  Just to let you know -- I think that this is what you asked for (as close as it comes, it's not pretty or nice). For a production solution I would recommend a tiny sub of your own, which then may write it out clearly as it's out of the way. (Then you can do even more there.)  It makes sense design-wise, since it does handle something particular.

Answer (score -1):

```
sub deref {
    map ref($_) eq 'ARRAY'? @$_ : ref($_) eq 'HASH'? %$_ : $_, @_
}

sub myCompExpr {
    1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6], {Hello => 'world', Answer => 42}
}

print $_ for deref myCompExpr
```